# Is there a Silverlight Decompiler Available?

Tags: silverlight

Is there any silverlight decompiler available?

Comment: Is this for a legitimate purpose? :)

Answer (score 11):

Nothing specific to my knowledge, but you can open the xap file (it's just a zip file) and use Reflector to decompile the dlls.

Answer (score 7):

JetBrains have made [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) available. It is currently free (hope it stays that way, unlike .Net Reflector).

It will also convert Silverlight DLLs all the way back to readable source code! I have tried it on several SL projects and it works like a charm.

**Note: as of the time of this writing it still gets a couple of things wrong: string concatenations and event handlers generate the wrong code.*

Answer (score 4):

XAPs are just zip files, so you can crack them open and decompile the code using Reflector. Also, it's worth taking a look at [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/).

Answer (score 2):

It's all .Net so you can just use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)